# python-docx change default bullet point style

Tags: python, python-docx

I am attempting to replicate a template word document using python-docx, one section of this document involves creating bullet points, which i can do easily adding the 'List Style 3' style to a paragraph.

However, this is gives me the default bullet, which is a solid black circle (•). I am trying to have the default bullet character be (-), which is actually one of the options under the 'Bullet Library'.

I have checked the paragraph styles documentation and did not see any option to modify this

Is there a feature to modify the default character used when creating bullet points?